# Laravel gt() broken?

Tags: laravel

Here is what i have, it enter in my IF when comparing two dates that we can see in the INFO that is not correct

As we can see in spanish is that: $date is greater than $schedule['timezone_end'] and u can see, date is 21:00 and scheduleTimeEnd is 22:30 of same day...

Any idea? thanks all
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser que estes comparando fechas con timezones diferentes ? Y el +n o -n se haga en tiempo de ejecucion ? Revisa el timezone principal de laravel y el de tu configuracion global de php por si a caso, una prueba rapida es parsear ambas fechas a Carbon y setearles un timezone, pero si estan mal de base hara la sumas/restar horarias mal de base

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En este sitio solo en español. Traduce tu pregunta o usa el sitio en inglés